# Regex works in test file, not in program (HTTP raw response)

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to debug a regex, and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why it works in the test file, but not elsewhere.

I am receiving a raw HTTP response, and have parsed out the section of interest:

```
UID:5F12F7DA-10B0-4EE3-820D-B56F0B2FC153
DTSTAMP:20120408T041113Z
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20120408T041113Z
DESCRIPTION:Testfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfgh
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20120410T000000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20120419T010000
LAST-MODIFIED:20120408T041228Z
LOCATION:Philadelphia\, PA
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
```

Each line ends in (hex:0D0A), which should be '\r\n'.

Here's the call for the summary:

$this->Summary = \Extract\Extract::GetSummary($vevent);

And here's the function:

```
public static function GetSummary($String) {
            $re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
            $re2='(SUMMARY)';   # Word 1
            $re3='(:)'; # Any Single Character 1
            $re4='(.*?)';   # Non-greedy match on filler
            $re5='(\r\n)';  # Any Single Character 2

            if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5."/is", $String, $matches))
            {

                $word1=$matches[1][0];
                $c1=$matches[2][0];
                $word2=$matches[3][0];
                return $word2;
            }

        }
```

Preg_match_all evaluates true in my test file, but false in my program. Any ideas? Something about the raw string it doesn't like, or isn't being copied into my test file (so I can't find it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using just the newline character as your final match:

```
function GetSummary($String) {
  $re1='.*?';       // Non-greedy match on filler
  $re2='(SUMMARY)'; // Token
  $re3='(:)';       // Separator
  $re4='(.*?)';     // Content
  $re5='\n';        // End of line

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5."/is", $String, $matches))
  {
    $word1=$matches[1][0];
    $c1=$matches[2][0];
    $word2=$matches[3][0];
    return $word2;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/zHr2X

If this still doesn't work, you might try using the end-of-line token `$`, or sanitize the line endings prior to calling the regex.